# Declaring and initializing a vector in C++ 17

Tags: c++, c++17

This code doesn't compile in VS Code for Mac.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using std::vector;
using std::cout;

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{23, 52, 9};

    for (int const& i : v)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello " << i << "!\n";
    }
}
```

Error:

```
hello.cpp:11:23: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    std::vector<int> v{23, 52, 9};
```

My c_cpp_properties.json suggests I'm using C++ 17.

This is the output of tasks.json:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-fcolor-diagnostics",
                "-fansi-escape-codes",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-fcolor-diagnostics",
                "-fansi-escape-codes",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/clang++"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

It is expecting me to not supply initial members of the array/list. Really weird. Same code works if I use the same declaration without initializing it, but using v.push_back().

Comment: What's the content of `tasks.json`? Have you followed the [guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc)?

Comment: `c_cpp_properties.json` is a file that only sets VSCode's editor features. It does not pass any data to the compiler

Comment: I have followed the guide.

Comment: [Nothing wrong with the code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MfW3LJRdj4rLeyUW).  Are you by any chance compiling it as C?

Comment: Also, why not use Xcode?

Comment: Ok, will try Xcode :) Any good Xcode C++ resources you can recommend?

Comment: "I have followed the guide" There's no "the" guide.You have followed some guide. Either the guide you have followed is bad, or you didn't follow it closely enough. I typed `vscode c++ mac` in a search box and got [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac#_troubleshooting) as the first result.

Comment: You should add `-std=c++17` to the `args`.

Comment: _Any good Xcode C++ resources you can recommend?_ Not really, no, I'm too familiar with it now to effectively answer that.  I'd just google around.  Also, you can install it (it's a free download from the App Store) and fire it up.  It comes with lots of project templates to get you started.

Comment: n. m. I've looked at the Microsoft guides for Mac, and nothing is working for me. It's exasperating. XCode works, so does CLion. No amount of editing the tasks.json works ("-std=c++17") etc.